# Convert date string to Date where Day is missing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know i can use to_date or parse to convert a string to a date in rails, but how do i convert to a date if the string is of the format "01-2018", where 01 is the month (January) and the day is missing ? Must be simple but i am having trouble doing it.

Trying it returns unexpected results, I am guessing because the day is missing:

```
3.0.2 :004 > Date.parse(x)  => Sun, 01 Jan 2023
3.0.2 :005 > x  => "01-2018"
3.0.2 :006 > x.to_date  => Sun, 01 Jan 2023
```

I guess i can prefix the string with sth like "01-", but is there a better way?

Comment: What’s your expected result? 1st of January?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Date.strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime). This method receives the string and format of the date:

```rb
date_str = "01-2023"
date = Date.strptime(date_str, "%m-%Y")
puts date # 2023-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

```rb
Date.strptime("12-2011", "%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the missing day?

```rb
Date.parse("01-" + x)
```

Comment: I have thought of that, but it's more like a hack frankly.